# If always gives same result, even if condition is true or false

Tags: shell, unix, csh

I need to have my input validated and receive a valid output based on the condition being true or false. Here even if my condition is true, I still get the false output. Where is my code wrong?

```
#
set input

#read -p "Who wrote the book Roots?" : input

#echo Who wrote the book Roots?
#read input

if($input == "Alex Haley")
      echo "bla bla"
else
      echo "bla bla bla"
endif
```

I commented out the method I used to obtain info, the both don't work.

`read -p input`, gives me:

```
read [9]: read: no query process
```

Comment: Is your question about `csh` since it doesn't look like `bash` to me? please add more accurate tags.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -n "Enter author: "

set input = "$<"

if ("$input" == "Alex Haley") then
      echo "bla bla"
else
      echo "bla bla bla"
endif
```

USAGE

```
> csh test.csh
Enter author: Alex Haley
bla bla
> csh test.csh
Enter author: Mark Twain
bla bla bla
>
```

Comment: @Juice, you need to supply the prompt.  I've updated my answer with a prompt and a couple of usage examples.

Comment: I get an event not found error, when i supply the prompt with a string that should result with bla bla, i get 0: Event not found, if i supply the prompt with bogus info, bla bla bla